# How to insert module into product page in prestashop

Tags: hook, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am creating a new module in Prestashop 1.6 which displays some data on the products page in the info box. I have created a new hook in the install method of the module like this: `$this->registerHook('combinationDescription')` and created the `hookDisplayCombinationDescription` function for assigning some smarty variables and displaying them with a tpl file. 
After installing my module the hook is registered into the database so its usable. 
Manually I can insert code into the product.tpl file just like: `{hook h="hookDisplayCombinationDescription"}` and I think it's working, but I would like to make this step automatically when the module gets installed. How can I do that?
My guess would be that to edit the product.tpl file from the install method of the module but it's a bit dirty method for me. Is there some other nice way to do that?

Comment: If you want to "add automatically" you need to choose one of existing HOOKS and prepare method for that one... :-) e.g. `displayProductButtons`, and really just hope that theme developers are smart enaugh not to remove default hooks :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you made a custom `hook` you need to insert its execution somewhere manually: into `.tpl` or into overrided `ProductController.php` (if it is an action hook). Prestashop can't execute it automatically for it doesn't know where do you want to execute it.

But you can use **the default Prestashop 1.6 hooks** to make your part of the code hooked and ready after the module installation. For the **product** page are these:

```
displayLeftColumnProduct
displayRightColumnProduct
displayProductTab
displayProductTabContent
displayFooterProduct
displayProductButtons
displayProductPriceBlock
actionProductOutOfStock
```

You can use one of these hooks and position your content with `css` (or `javascript` - to any part of the page).

[image: Product page hooks.]

Comment: In my case right now I have to display something inside the product info box (where price, title, social buttons, etc... are displayed). There is no hook on that part. How can I place my hook right there?

Answer (score 0):

If you make any custom hook then you have to make it executable first.Prestashop can't execute custom hooks automatically.But for displaying some data on product page you can use predefined prestashop hooks.Some are following

```
displayProductButtons
displayProductTab
```

To use these hooks, first you have to register hooks in install function like

```
     public function install()
        {
           if (!parent::install() || !$this->registerHook('displayProductButtons')){

           }
        }
```

and in the same file you have to make a function like

```
     public function hookDisplayProductButtons($params)
        {


        }
```

Now in that function you can assign some smarty variables which you want to access or show in your tpl file like

```
    public function hookDisplayProductButtons($params)
        {
             $this->smarty->assign(array(
                    'product_name' => 'abc'
                ));
        }
```

Now in your tpl file you can access that

Comment: What if we need to extend the product.tpl so we don't tweak the original product.tpl? That way we will be more futureproof and resilient to upgrades.
Do we do ?

{extends file='product.tpl'}
{block}
  <h1>"Example"</h1>
{/block}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add new custom hook and execute them when your particular module is active or installed.

Please follow the following steps:

1. Add you new custom hook code any where you want to perform your action.
2. Then, you can insert entry for that new custom hook into database at the time of installing module.
3. Now, your hook will execute as per your need.
4. Delete the same entry of hook from database at the time of uninstalling module so that hook could not be executed after uninstalling module.

I am not sure for, Is any other solution available to fulfill your need in prestashop?